# Jquery function not deleting parent class

Tags: jquery

Im trying to delete div with class `"order"` but it's not working.
I tried many solutions like

```
- $(this).parents('.order').remove();
- $(this).closest('.order').remove();
- $(this).parents.remove();
- $(this).parents('.order').remove();








 <div class = "order">
    <div class="skladniki">
      <p>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
       $(this).parent().remove(); 

       if($(".skladniki span").length == 0){
              $(this).parents().remove();
              console.log("działa");
       }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasoning is that once you remove the element it has no parents since it's no longer in the DOM

Store references before you remove it.

Something like:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();

  if ($parent.siblings().length) {
    $parent.remove()
  } else {
    $parent.closest('.order').remove()
  }
});
```

```css
.order {
  border: 1px solid green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order">
  <div class="skladniki">
    <p>
      <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
      <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
      <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
      <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you  my friend :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is how you can delete div using class property

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="hello">Hello</div>
      <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
  </div>

$( ".hello" ).remove();
```

This will result in a DOM structure with the  element deleted:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

`$(this).closest('.order').remove();` Is working just fine.

Removing the button from the DOM means that you can no longer find its parents and etc. because it's no longer related to them. Remove the `order` using something that is still in the DOM like the `<p>`.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $paragraph = $this.closest('p');  
  
  // Remove the clicked span
  $this.parent().remove();   
  
  if($paragraph.find('span').length == 0){
    $paragraph.closest('.order').remove(); 
  }
});
```

```css
.order {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "order">
    <div class="skladniki">
      <p>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
        <span> example <button class='remove'>x</button></span>
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But I need to remove "order" class when all spans are deleted thats why i put it in if statment. In my if - these ideas are not working

Comment: @PolakRobak Also, you should update your question to make it more clear what you are trying to do.